# Add OkHttp to my project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to add `OkHttp` to my project, i download both `OkHttp` and `Okio` library and add it to the `libs` directory.

than i add the compile methods:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I try to Build the App and i get this error:

```
Error:(27, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'APP'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Any idea what can be the problem? i am using Android Studio om mac OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete this line of your root gradle :

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

And Add this to your dependencies's app's module build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two build.gradle files in our project.

1. Top level gradle (can be found in the project directory)
2. Module level gradle (present inside the app folder of the project)

Here the problem is you are compiling the okHttp 
`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'`in the Top level gradle file try to place it in your Module level gradle. Also if you are importing a library using gradle you don't have to add it in the lib folder explicitly

[Google gradle documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)